# I have noticed that in Xcode 13 sometimes in projects the "Products" group containing the deliverables some times is not visible. Any solution?

Tags: xcode

I am using Xcode 13 for some tasks, although it is still in beta, and I have noticed that it happens quite often that the "Products" group/folder of a project is not visible in the project navigator. I suspect there might be a new project setting about it, but I did not yet find it, so I was wondering is somebody has already discovered it. Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That's just how Xcode 13 works. In a new project created in Xcode 13, there is no Products category (group) visible in the Project navigator any longer. This is covered in the release notes:

> The project navigator hides the Products group when it’s in the default location. The Product > Show Build Folder in Finder menu item replaces the most common use. (71561549)

Comment: that's mean a lot to me, thank you point out.

Answer (score 1):

when i used `pod install`, the `products` file will appear.

I checked the `.xcodeproj` file. I found that `products` file always exists.

I tested it. It seems that the result is affected by the configuration of `baseConfigurationReference` which in `.xcodeproj` file.

If at least one file description exists in the `Recovered References` folder, the products folder will be displayed.